# dynamic row insertion in table through php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have 3 rows. Which are dynamic created. If we click on  **add more** then all are three fields create dynamically. It is properly working.

But I want to insert these fields in to table through mysql query dynamically. I tried but it s not working. please help anyone to solve it. Thankyou.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var rowCount = 1;

     window.addMoreRows = function(frm) {
     rowCount++;
        var recRow = '<div id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><div class="col-sm-3 text-left">College Name:</div><div class = "col-sm-9"><input type="text" name = "collegename[]" placeholder = "College Name" class = "form-control"/></div><div class = "col-sm-3 text-left" > Affiliated University: </div><div class = "col-sm-9" ><input type = "text" name = "univ[]" placeholder = "Affiliated University" class = "form-control" / > </div><div class = "col-sm-3 text-left" > Course Name: </div> <div class = "col-sm-9" ><input type = "text" name = "cname[]" placeholder = "Course Name" class = "form-control"/></div><div class = "col-sm-3 text-left" > Major & Subject: </div><div class = "col-sm-9"><input type = "text" name = "msub[]" placeholder = "Major Subject" class = "form-control"/></div><div class = "col-sm-3 text-left"> Final & Percentage: </div><div class = "col-sm-9"><input type = "text" name = "fper[]" placeholder = "Final Percentage" class = "form-control"/></div><a href = "javascript:void(0);" onclick = "removeRow (' + rowCount + ');" >Delete</a></div> ';
$('#addedRows').append(recRow);
 }
 window.removeRow = function(removeNum) {
  $('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
 }
  </script>
  <?php
   extract($_POST);
     if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    if ($_POST['dynfields']) { 
   foreach (array_keys($dynfields) as $key) {
  $txt = $dynfields[$key];
  $txt1 = $univ[$key];
  $txt2 = $cname[$key];
  $txt3 = $msub[$key];
 $txt4 = $fper[$key];
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dynamicfield VALUES ('','','$txt','$txt1','$txt2','$txt3','$txt4')");

  }
   }
     echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong> Hobbies Added</h2></i>";
  mysql_close();
   }
    ?>
       <form action="" method="post" id="addedRows">
         <h5 align="left"><u style="color:#449D44;">Other Studies</u>-<span style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);">Add More Other Studies</span></h5>
    <span  id="rowId">
     <div class="col-sm-3 text-left">College&nbsp;Name: </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="dynfields[]" placeholder="College Name" class="form-control" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-3 text-left">Affiliated&nbsp;University: </div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="univ[]" placeholder="Affiliated University" class="form-control" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-left">Course&nbsp;Name: </div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="cname[]" placeholder="Course Name" class="form-control" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-left">Major&nbsp;Subject: </div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="msub[]" placeholder="Major Subject" class="form-control" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-left">Final&nbsp;Percentage: </div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="fper[]" placeholder="Final Percentage" class="form-control" /></div>
</span>
<input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: What is column name ?

Comment: name, email, mobile

Comment: Use column name in query , see my ans

Comment: I have updated. Please check. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find where you named your input fields.

Name your submitted input fields according to the array you want to retrieve from the $_POST parameter.

```
<input name="dynfields[]"/>
```

The Brackets tell PHP that a submitted value is part of an array.
In your edited question the HTML would be like this.

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="dynfields[]"  type="text"  value="" size="17%"/></td>
    <td><input name="dynfields1[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="dynfields2[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="dynfields[]"  type="text"  value="" size="17%"/></td>
    <td><input name="dynfields1[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="dynfields2[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
</tr>
(...)
```

After submitting the form you should be able to access 3 separate arrays:

```
$_POST['dynfields'];
$_POST['dynfields1'];
$_POST['dynfields2'];
```

Comment: I have updated..Its running. But after submit, only 0,0,0,0,0 are going in table.

Comment: Check first if the expected values are probperly received after the submit: print_r($yourarray);
If your values are correct right before the insert, check if your exactly "8" table columns are all of a text type like varchar or text.

Comment: before insert query data is properly showing. But only 0 values are inserting and table count are also right.

Comment: In insert query I type constant 'email'. But it is taking 0 value.

Comment: did you check the data types specified for the columns? Best post the table definition too in your question.

Comment: Thanks its working. There were int type fields in table. But I was inserting vachar data. So it was taking 0.   Thank you for help.

Comment: I have one more query.  Here is the dynamic insertion. But hw can I fetch data dynamically. We dont know how many rows will be in table.

Comment: Means in same form I want to fetch rows, In which they are inserted.

Comment: Fetch the Data from the Database and then iterate through the array rendering one tablerow for each result row until your table of input fields is complete. There should be plenty of examples for selecting data from mysql with php and iterating through the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.